# Rails method draggable_element don´t work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, element, draggable

I´m doing a e-commerce web page with Ruby on Rails. I´ve a shopping cart whose items must be draggable. 
I´ve the views for this as partial "_books.html.erb" with the method:

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
<li class="book" id="book_<%= book.id %>">
 ........
</li>
 **<%= draggable_element("book_#{book.id}", :revert => true) %>**
 <% end %>
```

But when I try to drag an element, appear this message:

undefined method `draggable_element' for #<#:0xac7c950>

I searched online in case the method was deprecated, but this method is for rails 3.0.0 ... Does anyone know what can happen?

Thanks, ilr

Comment: What version of rails are you using? Are you using Rails 3.0.0 or are you using something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the apidock: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/ScriptaculousHelper/draggable_element

This feature has been deprecated since V 3.0.9

Comment: I´m looking for methods to do an draggable element with ruby rails...if you know something like this...let me know please, thanks very much!